# No se como hacer esta operacion MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

```
$sql = "UPDATE inventarios_b stock = stock - :dato1 WHERE codigo_item = :dato2 ";
```

Me manda error , lo que quiero es restar al stock lo que tengo en `dato1`

Comment: Que error te da?

Comment: no se conecta, pero apra poder hacer eso sacas el folio de otra tabla, pero creo que no documentario bien y aparte no existe SET

Comment: No existe SET? Eso no lo entendí

Comment: Agrega tu código y por favor también agrega el mensaje de error

Comment: compañeros gracias, era la conexion en el servidor, se estaba utilizando un vpn y cuando se conectaba una vez te sacaba de la conexion, gracias por su atencion

Comment: Perfecto discupa, casi no se usar esta plataforma:
La solucion aparte del SET, es que el VPN no funcionaba correctamente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seguramente te da error porque te falta SET.

```
$sql = "UPDATE inventarios_b SET stock = stock - :dato1 WHERE codigo_item = :dato2 ";
```

Prueba eso y a ver qué dice.